# boolean controller inside animatedContainer not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Im a noob with animations.
I have an AnimatedContainer and a button, inside the button onPressed: 
 I'm trying to use a bool (the bool is declared on the top of the file)  to control my AnimatedContainer but I can't figure it out why the value of the boolean isn't changing after I update it inside the setState method, can anyone help me, please?

```
//bool 
 var isActive = false;
Center(
        child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
          if(isActive) {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.indigo;
              height = 100.0;
              width = 100.0;
              isActive = false;
            });
          }
          else {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.teal;
              height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
              width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
              isActive = true; 
            });
          }
          print(isActive);
```

Comment: could you add the full code? here:  gist.github.com

Comment: Sure 
https://gist.github.com/Psiale/48a23cf6c8533736b1c378e41719b940